# Dynamically Styled Button in React Native using Styled Components

Tags: button, react-native, styled-components

A Button component is generally comprised of the Text element wrapped with a TouchableHighlight (or other touchable). I'm trying to create a Button component styled using styled-components, but am having trouble getting my style to respond dynamically to props.

## Button Component

Below, I've created a Button component similar to the [Adapting based on props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) example found in the styled-component docs.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const colors = {
    accent: '#911',
    highlight: '#D22',
    contrast: '#FFF',
}

const Label = styled.Text`
  color: ${props => !props.outline ? colors.contrast : colors.accent};
  font-weight: 700;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px;
`

const ButtonContainer = styled.TouchableHighlight`
  background-color: ${props => props.outline ? colors.contrast : colors.accent};
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-color: ${colors.accent};
  border-width: 2px;
`

const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <ButtonContainer
            onPress={props.onPress}
            underlayColor={colors.highlight}
        >
            <Label>
                {props.children}
            </Label>
        </ButtonContainer>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

## Button Usage

After importing it, I'm using the button like this...

```
    <Button
      outline
      onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}>
      Press Me!
    </Button>
```

## Expected Result

And so, I would expect my button to look like this...

[image]

## Actual Result

But instead it looks like this...
[image]

## What I've done to troubleshoot so far

When I inspect using [react-devtools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools), I can see that the `outline` prop is being passed down to the `Button` component.

[image]

But the prop is not passed down to any of it's children

[image]

The [Passed Props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) part of the docs state, "styled-components pass on all their props", but I guess not all the way down?

## My Question

What do I need to change so that I can dynamically style my Button based on it's props?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have:

```
const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <ButtonContainer underlayColor={colors.highlight}>
            <Label>
                {props.children}
            </Label>
        </ButtonContainer>
    );
};
```

If `ButtonContainer` was a normal React component, you wouldn't expect the `props` passed to `Button` to be automatically passed to `ButtonContainer`. You'll have to do `<ButtonContainer underlayColor={colors.highlight} {...props} />` to do it.

Actually `ButtonContainer` is a normal React component, the only difference is you pre-apply some styles using an HOC.

Also if you desugar this to a `React.createElement` call, you can see there's no way `props` can be passed automatically, because a Function's arguments don't get passed automatically to the function calls inside it.

```
const Button = (props) => {
    return React.createElement(ButtonContainer, { underlayColor: colors.highlight }, ...);
};
```

It's nothing specific to `styled-components`. You just have to pass down the props yourself to `ButtonContainer`, as well as to `Label`.

So you'd rewrite your code to:

```
const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <ButtonContainer underlayColor={colors.highlight} onPress={props.onPress} outline={props.outline}>
            <Label outline={props.outline}>
                {props.children}
            </Label>
        </ButtonContainer>
    );
};
```

Technically a React component can pass down props to it's children, so `ButtonContainer` could pass them down to `Label` using `React.Children` and `React.cloneElement` APIs. But `ButtonContainer` doesn't do that for obvious reasons, e.g. you'd not want `underlayColor` and `onPress` to be passed to `Label` automatically. It would cause a lot of confusing bugs.

Comment: Thanks Satya! This all makes perfect sense. Thanks for writing such a great explanation, and of course it works just as you described it.

Comment: To add to @satya164's answer, you can immediately inherit all props like this: `<ButtonContainer {...props} underlayColor={colors.highlight}>`. That way you won't need to manually add every new prop you want to pass on.